Steepest descent method for $\min f=\sqrt{x_1^2+cx_2^2}$ for fix $c>1$

Want to prove $$\mathbf{x}_k=\left(\frac{c-1}{c+1}\right)^k\left(c,(-1)^k\right)^T$$

My attempt:
$$\mathbf{x}_0=(c,1)^T, \ \ \ \nabla f(\mathbf{x}_0)=\left(\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2+c}},\frac{c^2}{\sqrt{c^2+c}}\right)^T \ .$$
Find $\alpha_0$ such that: $$f( \ \mathbf{x}_0-\alpha_0\nabla f(\mathbf{x}_0) \ ) \ .$$
However, everything gets complex afterwards.
Is there any other simpler method?
Thanks!

The derivatives of $f$ are: $$ \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_1} = \dfrac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + cx_2^2}}, \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x_2} = \dfrac{cx_2}{\sqrt{x_1^2 + cx_2^2}}  $$ So $\nabla f(x_0) = \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 + c}}(1, 1)$

Like I said in the comment, $\nabla f(x_0) = \dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 + c}}(1, 1)^T$, not $\dfrac{c}{\sqrt{c^2 + c}}(1, {\color{red}c})^T$ in your post
Now, to choose $\alpha_0$, note that the steepest gradient descent only care about the direction, so it is sufficient to choose $\alpha_0$ such that
$$
     f(x_0 - \alpha_0 (1, 1)^T) = \min_{\alpha > 0} f(x_0 - \alpha (1, 1)^T)
$$
We have,
$$
   \begin{align*}
      f(x_0 - \alpha(1, 1)^T) &= f(c - \alpha, 1 - \alpha) = \sqrt{(c - \alpha)^2 + c(1 - \alpha)^2}\\
 &= \sqrt{c^2 - 2\alpha c + \alpha^2 + c(1 - 2\alpha + \alpha^2)}\\
 &= \sqrt{\alpha^2(1 + c) - 4\alpha c+c^2 + c}
   \end{align*}
$$
The quadratic under the square root sign is minimize when
$$
    \alpha = \alpha_0 = \dfrac{2c}{1+c} > 0
$$
Thus,
$$
   x_1 = \left(c - \dfrac{2c}{1 + c}, 1 - \dfrac{2c}{1+c}\right)^T = \dfrac{c - 1}{c + 1}\left(c, -1\right)^T
$$
